# PySide2 videoplayer: play .mp4 video from url works under MacOSX but not Windows and not Linux

Tags: python, video, playback, pyside2, qmediaplayer

I created a video player that plays a .mp4 video from the web by a given URL (hard coded to simplify). The code snippet builds up on this link: https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtMultimedia/QMediaPlayer.html#detailed-description

The video player works successfully in MacOSX, meaning it plays the video. It does however not work under Windows 10 and also not under Linux (Centos7). What is missing to get it working for Windows 10 and Linux (Centos7)?

```
import sys
from PySide2 import QtCore
from PySide2 import QtGui
from PySide2 import QtWidgets
from PySide2.QtMultimedia import QMediaPlayer, QMediaPlaylist
from PySide2.QtCore import QUrl
from PySide2.QtMultimediaWidgets import QVideoWidget


class VideoPlayer(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(VideoPlayer, self).__init__()
        self.player = QMediaPlayer()
        self.resize(QtCore.QSize(400, 300))        

        self.playlist = QMediaPlaylist(self.player)
        self.playlist.addMedia(QUrl("http://mirrors.standaloneinstaller.com/video-sample/star_trails.mp4"))

        self.video_widget = QVideoWidget()
        self.player.setVideoOutput(self.video_widget)

        self.playlist.setCurrentIndex(0)
        self.player.setPlaylist(self.playlist)

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.video_widget)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.player.play()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    player = VideoPlayer()
    player.raise_()
    player.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: you could run your code from the console or CMD and show the warnging you get.

Comment: In linux(Arch Linux) it works, I think you need to install some codec so it is necessary to show the console log.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I don't get any error message under Windows or Linux. All I get is a Window with a black video widget and nothing plays. Interestingly, mp4 videos are playable in Windows and Linux. I am not quit sure if that might be interesting, but I am running MacOSX as my main operating system and Windows and Linux via a VM using parallels.

Comment: in windows install http://codecguide.com/about_kl.htm

Comment: n ubuntu I installed the gstreamer codecs: https://github.com/eyllanesc/python-qt-docker/blob/master/Dockerfile#L34 , you should look for the equivalent packages in centos

Comment: On the other hand, using a VM can add one more layer of bug. Are you sure you have configured your VM correctly? I recommend you use that they have machines installed with the OS that you point out to avoid problems caused by the VM.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I will try the code snippet on 'real' machines (meaning no VMs). If [this post](https://forum.qt.io/topic/57675/which-file-formats-or-codecs-does-qmediaplayer-support/3) is correct then this might indeed be a problem with missing codecs on my VM

Comment: I confirm that the issue I ran into seems to be only happening on my VM. On a 'real' operating system this issue does not happen. So this might be quite likely simply an issue with a missing codec. Thanks for the tips.